# sql server folder questions

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I thought I read somewhere that in 'denali' we would be able to place tables within management studio into logical folders. For example I have 20 tables releating to clouds, i could create a clouds folder and group the tables logical, thus i can hide/expand that folder to see the tables. **Is this already done in 2008 r2?** **Or did i read correctly and it will happen in denali?**

Comment: I guess you are talking about SQL Management Studio?

Comment: Yes, Strictly sssms. Unless there is another way to view that I dont know of that has ssms capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server Code-Named Denali (or likely to be officially named 2011), has released its CTP 1. Along with it is SQL Server Management Studio.

Within, as it stands today, you cannot organize tables into 'folders' for visual organization.

Answer (score 0):

There are many 3rd party solutions which could implement such a feature but MS has not implemented in their tools yet.

However, here is a potential solution:  Management studio does allow you to define a filter on the tables list.  If you are working on one area you can right click on the table leaf and select filter.  Maybe this will help to restrict your view to just the tables you are interested in working with at a given time.